# Bind multiple dropdownlists to same datasource using loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, for-loop

I have a form with 15 dropdownlists inside a table. I would like populate each ddl with the same values from a single datasource.

Instead of doing the below x 15:

```
ddl.datasource = x
ddl.databind()
```

Is it possible to loop through all the DDL's in a table and assign the datasource etc all in one go?

Something like this? (I know the code is wrong but I am unsure of the full correct code)

```
For Each ctrl In tblNetwork.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is DropDownList Then
            ddl.DataSource = usr
            ddl.DataBind()
        End If
Next ctrl
```

Seems a basic one but it's got me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting stumped because your method is only going to traverse the top-level controls since iterating over tblNetworks.Controls won't be recursive.

I think that this is, in general, a *very bad idea* because your page will suffer from the recursion that you need to make in order to catch all the dropdowns in the page. With that said, here's a solution (in C#, sorry) that will work, regardless of the level of nesting of your dropdown lists.

First, you need to create a helper method that flattens any IEnumerable so we can use LINQ:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>( this IEnumerable<T> e,  Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> f)
    {
        return e.SelectMany(c => f(c).Flatten(f)).Concat(e);
    }
}
```

And now your code becomes this:

```
var result = this.Controls.Cast<DropDownList>().Flatten(x=>x.Controls.Cast<DropDownList>());
DropDownList current;
foreach (var item in result)
{
    if (item is DropDownList)
    {
       current = item as DropDownList;
       current.DataSource = your_data_source;
       current.DataBind();
     }
 }
```

You can obviously extend this further to do the same on any page you need to, but the more complicated your page is, the bigger your performance hit.

I hope I persuaded you from doing this...

Comment: Thanks for the response Icarus, I'll try this out. I was just interested if there was a quicker way of binding all the ddls without repeating code over and over again. I guess it's not as straightforward as that?

Comment: What you want to do is simple (as evidenced in the code above) but is not performant in the general case. I've literally seen people doing this kind of recursion just to set a label's text that's on another container outside their current page and the performance was horrible (thousands of function calls) when you can solve the problem with ONE function call. Again, this will work but the performance is horrible when there's a lot of nesting (serve controls, inside other server controls and so on)